# codemirror : how to indent the whole line when pressing tab?

Tags: javascript, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I am creating a new simple mode for codemirror.

I would like that when the user presses "tab", the whole line gets indented (as opposed to only the part of the line that is after the cursor, "splitting" the line in two).

What would be the simplest way to do this ?

note : the corresponding code does not have to be defined in the mode. Any other approach (e.g. add on or configuration) would work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aljordan82/nktvt8vf/)

```
    extraKeys: {
        "Tab": function(cm){
            // get cursor position
            var pos = cm.getCursor();
            // set cursor position to the begining of the line.
            cm.setCursor({ line: pos.line, ch: 0 });
            // insert a tab
            cm.replaceSelection("\t", "end");
            // set cursor position to original.
            cm.setCursor({ line: pos.line, ch: pos.ch + 1 });
        }
     }
```

Comment: This breaks selection indenting: There is no more multi line indenting and when trying to indent a selection, the selection gets unselected afterwards

Comment: I wasn't aware of "indentMore". Your answer should be the accepted answer.

Comment: wirking with a lags

Answer (score 10):

Simply change tab's keymap to indentMore:

```
extraKeys: {
    "Tab": "indentMore"
}
```

This solution also doesn't break selection indenting.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nktvt8vf/12/)

Comment: Work fine for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the manual:

```
extraKeys: {
  'Tab': 'indentAuto'
}
```

- Extra keys: http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#option_extraKeys
- `indentAuto` command: http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#command_indentAuto